# How to set default function in codeIgniter when I visit Class with non-existent route?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

The controller like this:

```
class Abc extends CI_controller{
  public function index(){...}

  public function f1(){...} 
}
```

If url is `http://host/app/Abc/index` it get function index
If url is `http://host/app/Abc/f1` it get function f1
If url is `http://host/app/Abc` it get function index because it is default
But if url is `http://host/app/Abc/f2` it print 404 not found

I expected that if url is `http://host/app/Abc/f2` it can turn to index function.
If can't do this,I want to add new function automatically,What should I do?

**EDIT**
I want to use it in just a specific class, can I edit global routing? How?

Comment: I think you can set the rout of 404 to dafault rout

Comment: Does this requirement apply to any route (e.g., any nonexistent route ends up in the same index function) or only to a specific controller class?

Comment: @cafonso only to a specific controller class

Comment: @ShahRukh I want do this only to a specific controller class

Comment: then set the rout to default for that class/method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two ways you can do it first edit routes.php file and change 404_override to controller function this will redirect all your 404 request to that controller function

```
form
$route['404_override'] = 'welcome';

to
$route['404_override'] = 'ABC/index';
```

second option is within controller you can use _remap method/function to check either function/method exist or not. controller will be like this

```
class Abc extends CI_controller{

  function _remap($method_name = 'index'){

             if(!method_exists($this, $method_name)){
                $this->index();
             }
             else{
                $this->{$method_name}();
             }
         }

  public function index(){...}

  public function f1(){...} 
}
```

Comment: yes! I just read CI doc and found _remap ,and thinking how to use, then you came,so good! let me have a try

Answer (score 0):

Same, but using arguments.
If not, arguments will fail to pass, pagination, filtering, parameters will not work.

```
class Abc extends CI_controller{

    function _remap($method_name = '',$args){
                if(!method_exists($this, $method_name)){
                    //$this->index($args);
                    call_user_func_array  (array($this,'index'), $args);
                 }
                 else{
                    //$this->{$method_name}();
                    call_user_func_array  (array($this,$method_name),  $args);
                 }

             }
    public function index($a,$b,$c){...}

    public function f1($a,$b){...} 

}
```

Comment: Sometimes you need strict url, like /auth/index/ not /auth/.
`code
if(count($this->uri->segments) < 2) {
    redirect('auth/index/', 'refresh');
    die();
   }`

Answer (score -1):

Let me do some notes here and make a collection in my favorite,Thanks all very much!

```
class Abc extends CI_controller{

  function _remap($method_name = 'index'){

             if(!method_exists($this, $method_name)){
                $this->index($method_name);
             }
             else{
                $this->{$method_name}($method_name);
             }
         }

  public function index($method_name='index'){...}

}
```

effectively,I just want this _remap function because the methods I request are all non-existed.
This is good! Yes! I suddenly see the light!