# Why do I have to include index in URL CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have created a controller call posts like below

```
<?php

class Posts extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){

        $data['title'] = 'Latest posts';

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```

I have set routes like below

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['posts'] = 'posts/index';
```

but if I go to the url `http://localhost/Blog/posts` it dies with 404 page error

But if i go to `http://localhost/Blog/posts/index` it works fine

why I cant get it to work in the first url? what did I do wrong please help me with this i am new to codeigniter

Comment: Including index in URL is your choice, not made compulsory by CI. You can go through the codeIgniter user guide, answer is already there in stackoverflow, just google and use right keywords.  https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/urls.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter - Remove "Index" From URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734921/codeigniter-remove-index-from-url)

Comment: i need to load posts page its in posts controller index method why when i use `http://localhost/Blog/posts` its not working why i have to use index as well

Comment: plz check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176713/how-to-set-default-function-in-codeigniter-when-i-visit-class-with-non-existent

Comment: try changing `$route['posts'] = 'posts/index';`, to just `posts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `Blog` might be a subdirectory where you have your CodeIgniter installation.
CI will treat any incoming uri as `/controller/action/parameters` and try to instance the corresponding `Controller` class. If that's the case, it's trying to instance a controller named `Blog` and can't find it.

To fix this you have to update your `config.php` and set:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/Blog/';
```

Answer (score 0):

change $route['posts'] to **$route['/posts']** in router or remove that router since index method will get called as default.